# Why "should be doing" and not just "should do" in the following sentences?

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives, progressive-aspect, should

What is the difference between "should X" and "should be Xing" in the following contexts? Or are they interchangeable?

> - 10 Things you **should do** to improve the health of your hair.
> - 10 Things You **Should Be Doing** to Boost Your Immunity.

(From Google searches.) Is there any slight difference between using *should do* and *should be doing* there?

Likewise,

> I believe in making the world safe for our children, but not our children's children, because I don't think children **should be having** sex.
>   — Jack Handey

Would "I don't think children should have sex" be possible here?

Answer (score 4):

My sense of the difference is this:

*Ten things you should do* implies that the list will consist of things that you do once, and then you're done; for example, "lose 10 pounds" or "get your prostate checked."

*Ten things you should be doing* implies that the list consists of things that you have to develop as ongoing habits; for example, "get 30 minutes of exercise every day."

This distinction can easily be overridden by the details provided in the actual list, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you were my boss at work and you said "here are 10 things you should do", I would assume these were new projects, not yet undertaken, to put on the "to do" list.

If you said "here are 10 things you should be doing" I would be more likely to feel a sense of immediacy with an implied "should be doing NOW".

I would assume the writer of the second article title wished to convey a sense of urgency.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is "should do" is a one-time thing, whereas "should be doing" implies the continuous effort, i.e. a process.

In your example:

> 10 things **you should do** to improve the health of your hair

possibly means 10 things / tasks that you need to do. (For example, take medications, check with a doctor, etc)

> 10 Things You **Should Be Doing** to Boost Your Immunity.

can mean something that you should be doing constantly, such as exercising daily, taking healthy diet, etc.

In a sense, the first pattern can be used in place of the second one.

Answer (score -2):

What you "should do" means "the task is assign to you to accomplish" but what you "should be doing" means "it was assigned earlier on and I left it when in for something else".